# Is there an equivalent to Visual Studio's macro recording and playback facility in XCode?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio

I need to be able record a sequence of keystrokes in the XCode editor and play them back repeatedly in order to help with some repetitive editing I need to do. Microsoft Visual Studio has this ability (macro recording), so I'm just wondering if it's also possible in XCode.

Comment: You could try using automator

Comment: Antwan - thanks but I didn't really want to write a script - in VS I can just press <ctrl><shift>R to start recording - do whatever I want to create my macro e.g. move to the end of the line, insert some text, and move down one line, then press <ctrl><shift>R again to stop recording. I can then press <ctrl><shift>P repeatedly to playback my macro. If XCode has anything similar that would be great.

Comment: you don't need to write a script I think, you should be able to record the actions you perform. but then again its not really a "clean" solution. Just my 2 cents

Comment: When I need to use a macro, I open the file in Emacs and edit it. Anyway Xcode automatically reloads files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness, I'm answering my own question - there doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent in XCode.